# Debugging Expo web in vscode

Tags: react-native, debugging, visual-studio-code, expo, expo-web

I am trying to debug a React Native code running on Expo web locally using vscode.

I tried these configurations in `launch.json`:

```
    {
        "command": "npm start",
        "name": "Run npm start",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "node-terminal"
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach to packager",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": "19001",
    }
```

and in both cases Expo runs and the debugger attaches:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64192/13e8c77d-9c88-4909-9762-9b5bf8b70f90
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached
```

But the breakpoints are either unbounded or not working.

This is the scripts in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "expo start",
  "android": "expo start --android",
  "ios": "expo start --ios",
  "web": "expo start --web",
  "eject": "expo eject"
},
```

Any idea on what I'm missing?

Comment: This helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412994/cant-debug-expo-project-on-vscode