# ReactNative - Expo - Debugging with breakpoints

Tags: ios, react-native, debugging, visual-studio-code, expo

I have issues to start a debugger. I am using VS Code and I installed the react native tools.
My launch.json looks like this

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Attach to packager",
        "request": "attach",
        "type": "reactnative",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "port": 19001
    }
],
```

}

When I click on Debug Remote JS within my IOS simulator, I am redirected to http://localhost:19000/debugger-ui/

Here, it says Status: Disconnected from proxy. Attempting reconnection. Is node server running?

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the following to vscode settings file:

```
"react-native-packger.port": 19000
```

I found the answer in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57412994/cant-debug-expo-project-on-vscode):

Having said that, I am in the exact same boat as you and wanted to know if either you were able to fix the issue?

Comment: I guess, it depends on how you start your application. When I do it with "expo start", it doesn't work. If I use "npm start" instead, the debugger is attached. However, I still couldn't figure out how to use breakpoints though. But thanks for the help!